# Virtuoso Windows service not getting created

Tags: windows-services, virtuoso

As per the instructions in `virtuoso-t --help`:

```
To create a windows service 'MyService' using the configuration file c:\database\virtuoso.ini:
  virtuoso-t +service create +instance MyService +configfile c:\database\virtuoso.ini
```

I ran

> `virtuoso-t +service create +instance my-virtuoso +configfile D:\SOFT\Virtuoso\database\my-virtuoso.ini`

got

```
[Using my-virtuoso.ini in D:\SOFT\Virtuoso\database]
The Virtuoso_my-virtuoso service has been registered
  and is associated with the executable d:\soft\virtuoso\bin\virtuoso-t.exe
```

Service not showing in Windows services and not accessible on the port.

Is there a way to register a [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) service on [Windows 7](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Windows_7)?

BTW, [OpenLink](http://www.openlinksw.com/) people (as I am pretty sure you are reading this), your instructions say `To create a windows service 'MyService'` but the result of the command run reports equivalent to `Virtuoso_MyService`. Might want to correct that in your next release, in addition to the actual service creation or maybe the instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the flag on the incorrect `-?` output.  There are a few things that have changed and not been reflected properly there.  That will be fixed.

One of these is that you should find the Service is listed in the control panel as `OpenLink Virtuoso Server [MyService]`, which Windows knows as `Virtuoso_MyService`, and Virtuoso knows as `MyService` -- so the `-?` output should show --

> To start this service in the command-line, use
>
> `sc start Virtuoso_MyService`
>
> or
>
> `virtuoso-t +service start +instance MyService`
>
> To work with this service in the **Services** or **Component Services** control panel, look for **OpenLink Virtuoso Server [MyService]**.

Creating the Service does not start it; that's why it's not listening.

I have tested and confirmed all of the above on Windows 7, with both Open Source and Commercial Edition builds of version 7.2.4.2 (`07.20.3217`).

Comment: I thought that the Win 7 services console would show all the services regardless of their running status and allow you to start them if they are not already

Comment: Please look for *`OpenLink Virtuoso Server [my-virtuoso]`* in both `net start` output and OS services console...

Comment: I will just add that, in case a restart of a service fails, a likely reason is that the `*.lck` file still exists and needs to be deleted manually

Comment: The need to remove the `*.lck` file and myriad other answers to "why did something (not) happen?" are frequently found in the log file...

Comment: BTW, I just tried to register a service on `CentOS` for `7.2.4` and `virtuoso-t` doesn't have a `+service` option there.  it does on windows 7

Comment: CentOS is not Windows, and thus does not have any mechanisms by which to handle Windows Services...

Comment: I meant why is it not possible to register it as a service through the virtuouso API and not the OS (which I did do and it works)?

Comment: If your wish is for Virtuoso builds for (any-and-all) Linux to include support for a distro-specific (CentOS/RH/Fedora and derivatives) feature, I suggest you bring it to [the mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), or raise an issue against [the FOSS project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/).

Comment: dude -- `virtuoso-t -h` does a different listing of options for windows and Linux.  **for the same version of Virtuoso**  it doesn't include `+service`.  don't you think it's kind of inconsistent ?

Comment: another thing is that it doesn't come with a prepackaged command to shut down a server.  so to shut down, you have to go `isql 1111` and then `shutdown();` which needs to go in the ExecStop section in your *.service file on Linux. it's not that big a deal but it's something you need to think about when packaging your releases...

Comment: Ongoing exchanges like this are frowned on by the S-O community. Again, I encourage you to [bring your feedback to the Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), or [raise an issue against the project on Github](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/). That said, note that you can use `/path/to/isql <host>:<port> <uid> <pwd> EXEC=shutdown` in your `ExecStop` or similar. (Linux service management varies substantially across distributions and otherwise; there's no single answer for this.)